# sqlalchemy: multiple joins with different join types and specifying relationship to join on

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a multi-join where each subsequent table joins on the previously joined table with inner `join()` on the `relationship()` attribute but I want an `outerjoin()` for Table4.

The query looks like:

```
self.s.query(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4) \
      .join('relationship2', 'relationship3') \
      .outerjoin('relationship4') \
      .all()
```

What ends up happening is that Table4 attempts to join to Table1, instead of on `Table3.relationship4` as needed, producing InvalidRequestError:

```
InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class 'Table1'>' has no property 'relationship4'
```

How can I specify to the `outerjoin()` to use the natural foreign key relationship from Table3?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it's pretty simple if you specify the model class directly which is more robust, instead of trying to join on the `relationship()` attribute name. I believe this will only work if there is one foreign key relationship between the two tables. [SQLA join docs here.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)

For example, this will produce what I am looking for, with Table4 presented as `None` where there is no matching row:

```
self.s.query(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4) \
  .join('relationship2', 'relationship3') \
  .outerjoin(Table4) \ # reference the model class directly here
  .all()
```